# Java process notify Node event loop

Tags: java, node.js

If I have some Java code contained in a Java jar file, and my node.js process kicks off the jar file, how do I notify node.js when the Java process is done?

Comment: perhaps an answer lies herein https://github.com/joeferner/node-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the child process exits, the `child` object emits an [`exit` event](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_event_exit_2).

---

> ...but the [output] will be written somewhere in javaland, not nodeland, how do I best get that result into the node process?
>   
> ...
>   
> ...I don't understand how you tie output from the java process (System.out for instance) to Node.js

At the OS level, there are three character streams that all processes have: stdin, stdout, and stderr. ("std" = "standard".) When a process spawns a child process, it can write to the child's stdin (to send it input) and read from the child's stdout and stderr (to receive its output). This is the most basic form of inter-process communication, and astonishingly powerful. It's the same mechanism that's at work when you pipe the result of one command-line program into another (or to a file).

To read the output the Java program writes to `System.out` or `System.err`, you read from the Node child object streams [`stdout`](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_child_stdout) and [`stderr`](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_child_stderr).

Let's assume you've spawned your child process and saved it in variable `ch`. Here's how you'd read `stdout` and also receive notification when the process ends:

```
ch.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    var buff = new Buffer(data);
    console.log(buff.toString('utf8')); // Or whatever encoding you're using for output
});

ch.on('exit', function (code) {
    console.log('Child process exited with code ' + code);
});
```

Comment: thanks for the info, for me to assume that a node.js process automatically ties it's stdin/stdout to a child JVM process is a big leap that I never would never make or assume. I assumed the opposite- that you have to tell node.js explicitly to tie its stdin to Java's output, but yeah what you say makes sense, I don't know much about inter-process comm so this is good stuff for a newbie

Comment: @AlexMills: I've just updated the answer to include the info in the comments above and added a brief code example. Yeah, it's a one of those "light-bulb" moments. :-) The OS wires this particular thing up for you. That's why you see these same three things (in, out, err) in various technologies. But you don't know that until you know it. :-)

Comment: thanks, now, I just hope that OS level inter-process communications works on all of Windows, Mac and Linux, I will assume that's true

Comment: @AlexMills: Yes, it's true. It's a Unix concept that was present even in DOS, that's how fundamental it is. (Heck, for all I know, it's older than Unix, but I think it was Unix that started this, it's very much in keeping with how Unix works...) :-)